# How to serialize an HTML DOM including Shadow DOM?

Tags: javascript, html, dom, shadow-dom

I want to serialize an entire HTML DOM including Shadow DOM trees into a string i.e. including both the shadow host and shadow root in a way that they can be reconstructed.

I can programatically access the Shadow DOM via .shadowRoot.innerHTML but calling .outerHTML on the entire DOM or using an XMLSerializer does not include the shadowRoot.

Is there a way to serialize the entire HTML document including Shadow DOM trees?

Comment: Can you include `html`, `js` that you have tried at Question?

Answer (score 2):

> I want to serialize an entire HTML DOM including Shadow DOM trees into
>   a string i.e. including both the shadow host and shadow root in a way
>   that they can be reconstructed.

Note, `shadowRoot` nodes are not clonable; though you should be able to iterate `childNodes` of `shadowRoot` to retrieve `.nodeValue` or `.innerHTML` of each node within `shadowRoot`.

```
var elems = document.getElementById("host").shadowRoot.childNodes;
var shadowHTML = "";
for (var i = 0; i < elems.length; i++) {
  shadowHTML += elems[i].nodeValue || elems[i].outerHTML;
}
```

Alternatively you can call `.innerHTML` chained to `.treeRoot` property of `shadowRoot` to retrieve full `html` of `shadowRoot`.

```
var shadowHTML = document.getElementById("host").shadowRoot.treeRoot.innerHTML;
```

---

> I can programatically access the Shadow DOM via .shadowRoot.innerHTML
>   but calling .outerHTML on the entire DOM or using an XMLSerializer
>   does not include the shadowRoot.

You can use `.outerHTML` called on `.host` to retrieve `html` of element within `document` which hosts `shadowRoot`.

```
var host = document.getElementById("host").shadowRoot.host.outerHTML;
```

The `shadowRoot` can then be reconstructed by creating a `<template>` element, setting `.innerHTML` to variable `shadowHTML` which is string `.treeRoot.innerHTML`; appending newly created `template` element to a `shadowRoot`.

Comment: This sounds like an enormous amount of work compared to serializing via `a=elem.innerHTML` and de-serializing using `elem.innerHTML=a`...